# How to generate CPU and memory usage graphs after load/soak test?

Tags: java, performance

I am new to performance test. Learned from google that JMeter can be used to perform load and soak test for my spring boot application.

I have my JMeter scripts ready and I can trigger the test as scheduled. But I am not sure about the following things:

1. How to generate files(javacore ?) in jre with the information of CPU and memory usage during the test execution?
2. What tools can be adopt to generate CPU and memeory usage graphes ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JDK tool such as [JvisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/).
[image]
It can generate summary visualized report of cpu and memory situation

For more performance monitor and bottleneck location, you can taste [SJK](https://github.com/aragozin/jvm-tools?hmsr=toutiao.io&utm_medium=toutiao.io&utm_source=toutiao.io)
For example:

```
> java -jar sjk.jar ttop -p 6344 -n 20 -o CPU
    2013-09-09T11:32:45.426+0300 Process summary
  process cpu=31.08%
  application cpu=28.90% (user=6.40% sys=22.49%)
  other: cpu=2.19%
  heap allocation rate 5260kb/s
[000001] user= 3.12% sys=11.40% alloc=  762kb/s - main
[092018] user= 0.94% sys= 0.47% alloc=  335kb/s - RMI TCP Connection(16)-10.139.211.172
[092016] user= 0.31% sys= 1.56% alloc= 1927kb/s - SVN-WJGGZ
[092007] user= 0.78% sys= 8.75% alloc=  860kb/s - Worker-4863
[092012] user= 0.31% sys= 0.31% alloc=  429kb/s - Worker-4864
[091966] user= 0.16% sys= 0.00% alloc=   90kb/s - Worker-4859
[092022] user= 0.16% sys= 0.00% alloc=  6871b/s - JMX server connection timeout 92022
[000002] user= 0.00% sys= 0.00% alloc=     0b/s - Reference Handler
[000003] user= 0.00% sys= 0.00% alloc=     0b/s - Finalizer
[000004] user= 0.00% sys= 0.00% alloc=     0b/s - Signal Dispatcher
[000005] user= 0.00% sys= 0.00% alloc=     0b/s - Attach Listener
[000009] user= 0.00% sys= 0.00% alloc=     0b/s - Framework Active Thread
[000012] user= 0.00% sys= 0.00% alloc=     0b/s - Framework Event Dispatcher
[000014] user= 0.00% sys= 0.00% alloc=     0b/s - Start Level Event Dispatcher
[000015] user= 0.00% sys= 0.00% alloc=     0b/s - Bundle File Closer
[000018] user= 0.00% sys= 0.00% alloc=     0b/s - [Timer] - Main Queue Handler
[000019] user= 0.00% sys= 0.00% alloc=     0b/s - Worker-JM
[000029] user= 0.00% sys= 0.00% alloc=     0b/s - [ThreadPool Manager] - Idle Thread
[000030] user= 0.00% sys= 0.00% alloc=     0b/s - Java indexing
[000033] user= 0.00% sys= 0.00% alloc=     0b/s - com.google.inject.internal.util.$Finalizer
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It looks like that visualVm is good enough. But unfortunately that my remote server has JRE only but no JDK, thus no jstatd. Is it that visualVM not suitable for my case?

Comment: jvisulavm can startup and monitor a remote process. That is, you can start  jvisulavm in your own PC, and connect to a remote server

Comment: quoted from visualvm document "To retrieve and display information on applications running on the remote host, the jstatd utility needs to be running on the remote host. "    jstatd is from JDK but my remote server doesn't have

Comment: Then you maybe wanna use SJK

Comment: I finally use visualVM with JMX connection to monitor the CPU and memory usage of the remote server. Thanks for your idea.

Answer (score 0):

Your monitoring solutions should monitor technical behavior as well as application availability (response time, error rate..). A good monitoring solution can collect all your java instances and create an aggreated graph of your cluster... and alerting.

Nowadays Prometheus+Grafana are two very common open-source tools but there are other tools (DatadogHQ, Dynatrace).

When using Prometheus, you can use the jmx-exporter to collect Java (mbeans) metrics. see [this blog](https://grafana.com/blog/2020/06/25/monitoring-java-applications-with-the-prometheus-jmx-exporter-and-grafana/) for exemple.

[image: Grafana Screenshot]

### alternatively, a standalone solution

...To monitor a single remote sever (even without JMX connection)

If you don't want to setup a complete monitoring solution,  [Java melody](https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki) is easier to [install](https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki/UserGuide) on a server.

[image: javamelody Screenshot]

### Alternatively, for desktop users

to monitor a single java application on your desktop or on a remote server with jmx, the [JvisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/) explained in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48055064/1260896) by [Hash Jang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9130314/hash-jang) is a good solution.
[image: JvisualVM Screenshot]